# Does inequality for subset imply inequality for set?

Tags: inequality

Suppose I have two finite sets of numbers ($\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$) $A$ and $B$, each split into some $n$ disjoint subsets $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n$ and $B = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup ... \cup B_n$, and let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, A_2, ...,A_n \}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \{B_1, B_2, ...,B_n \}$.

If there exists a one-to-one matching of each $B_i \in \mathcal{B}$ to a $A_j \in \mathcal{A}$ such that
$$\frac{\sum_{k\in B_i}k}{|B_i|} \geq \frac{\sum_{k\in A_j}k}{|A_j|}$$
(e.g. if $A_1$ is used for $B_1$ in the relation above, then $B_2$ cannot use $A_1$ anymore)

Does it imply $$\frac{\sum_{k \in B} k}{|B|} \geq \frac{\sum_{k \in A} k}{|A|}?$$

Intuitively, if each of the subset average in $B$ is $\geq$ a unique subset average in $A$ (one-to-one matching), does that imply $B$'s average is $\geq$ $A$'s average?

Comment: Just want to make a note about notation:

"$\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, A_2, ...,A_n \}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \{B_1, B_2, ...,B_n \}$"

makes sense, and

"$\mathcal{A} = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n$ and $\mathcal{B} = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup ... \cup B_n$"

also makes sense, but these can't both be true at the same time. The former is saying that each $A_i$ (resp. $B_i$) is an *element* of $\mathcal{A}$ (resp. $\mathcal{B}$), but the latter is saying that each $A_i$ (resp. $B_i$) is a *subset* of $\mathcal{A}$ (resp. $\mathcal{B}$). However, $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is disjoint from its power set.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think it's a case of misused notation. The OP probably intend to mean the second version.

Comment: Apologies, edited the question to make it (hopefully) right! :)

Comment: I think you should write $i \in \{1,...,n\}$

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. The question has been answered! Though I do have a variant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731684/does-inequality-for-subset-imply-inequality-for-set-ordered-numbers

Comment: This seems like a variant of Simpson's Paradox. E.g. when testing a new drug, a higher percentage of women than men were cured in each of two trials, but the combined data from both trials showed a higher percentage of men than women cured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=A_1\cup A_2$ and $B=B_1\cup B_2$, where $A_1=\{1.0,1.1,1.2\}$, $A_2=\{2.1\}$, $B_1=\{1\}$, and $B_2=\{2\}$; then

$$\frac{\sum A_1}{|A_1|}=1.1>1=\frac{\sum B_1}{|B_1|}$$

and

$$\frac{\sum A_2}{|A_2|}=2.1>2=\frac{\sum B_2}{|B_2|}\;,$$

but

$$\frac{\sum A}{|A|}=1.35<1.5=\frac{\sum B}{|B|}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for the nice counterexample! I have a variant here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731684/does-inequality-for-subset-imply-inequality-for-set-ordered-numbers

Comment: @Nicholas: You’re welcome!