# Does inequality for subset imply inequality for set? (Ordered numbers)

Tags: inequality

Suppose I have two ordered (decreasingly), finite sets of numbers ($\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$) $A$ and $B$, each split into some $n$ disjoint subsets $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n$ and $B = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup ... \cup B_n$. (Ordered means for instance, $A = 10,10, 9, 8, ....$ and $B = 16, 15, ...$, and I chop it up into equal number of disjoint subsets each)

If for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$
$$\frac{\sum_{k\in B_i}k}{|B_i|} \geq \frac{\sum_{k\in A_i}k}{|A_i|}$$

Does it imply $$\frac{\sum_{k \in B} k}{|B|} \geq \frac{\sum_{k \in A} k}{|A|+1}?$$

Comment: What do you mean by *ordered*? I would interpret this question to be the same as the [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731624/does-inequality-for-subset-imply-inequality-for-set).

Comment: Added a clarification :) So for instance A = 10, 10, 9, 8... and B = 16, 15, ..., then I chop it up into equal number of disjoint subsets, and if the relation hold (now both are same index i), does it imply the same result?

Comment: Does "ordered decreasingly" mean the minimum element of $A_i$ is not smaller than the maximum element of $A_{i+1}$?

Comment: My previous counterexample still works (with a little renaming): order $A$ as $2.1,1.2,1.1,1.0$ and $B$ as $2,1$, let $n=2$, and let $A_1=\{2.1\}$ and $B_1=\{2\}$.

Comment: @Divide1918 yea that's right

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're right! Sorry let me add one additional condition :) The final inequality's denominator added by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=\{2.1,1.2,1.1,1.0\}$, with $B_1=\{2.1\}$ and $B_2=\{1.2,1.1,1.0\}$. Let $A$ contain $100$ copies of $2$ and $100$ copies of $1$, with the $2$s in $A_1$ and the $1$s in $A_2$. Then

$$\frac{\sum B_1}{|B_1|}=2.1>2=\frac{\sum A_1}{|A_1|}\;,$$

and

$$\frac{\sum B_2}{|B_2|}=1.1>1=\frac{\sum A_2}{|A_2|}\;,$$

but

$$\frac{\sum B}{|B|}=1.35<\frac{100}{67}=\frac{\sum A}{|A|+1}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks again for your great help. I have imposed again additional conditions (this time much more refined) in a new variant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732347/ordered-set-inequality

Answer (score 1):

As a counterexample, if
\begin{align*}
&B_1=\{12\}\;\;&&\;\;B_2=\{62\}\\[8pt]
&A_1=\{10\}\;\;&&\;\;A_2=\{30,60,90\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
then
$$
\frac{\sum_{\Large{B_1}}}{|B_1|}=\,12\; > \;10=\,\frac{\sum_{\Large{A_1}}}{|A_1|}
\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;
\frac{\sum_{\Large{B_2}}}{|B_2|}=\,62\; > \;60=\,\frac{\sum_{\Large{A_2}}}{|A_2|}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,
$$
but
$$
\frac{\sum_{\Large{B}}}{|B|}=\,37\;\;< \;\;38=\;\frac{\sum_{\Large{A}}}{|A|+1}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have another variant here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732347/ordered-set-inequality :)