# Ordered Set Inequality

Tags: inequality

Suppose I have two (decreasingly) ordered finite set of numbers ($\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$) $A$ and $B$, each split into some disjoint sets $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n \cup A_{n+1}$ and  $B = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup ... \cup B_n$.

*Ordered in this case means, for instance, A = 20, 10, 9, 8, ... and B = 16, 15, ..., and I chop it up into n+1 and n (contiguous) disjoint sets respectively (respecting the ordering - when chopping, the elements have to maintain its initial relative ordering. So the minimum element of $A_i$ is greater than the maximum element of $A_{i+1}$)

If:

$$\frac{\sum_{k \in A_1 \cup ... \cup A_i} k}{|A|} \leq \frac{\sum_{k \in B_1 \cup ... \cup B_i} k}{|B|} \text{ for all } i \in \{1, ..., n\}$$
$$\frac{\sum_{k \in A_1 \cup ... \cup A_{i+1}} k}{|A|} > \frac{\sum_{k \in B_1 \cup ... \cup B_i} k}{|B|} \text{ for all } i \in \{1, ..., n\}$$
$$\text{Particularly, } \ \frac{\sum_{k \in A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n} k}{|A|} > \frac{\sum_{k \in B_1 \cup ... \cup B_n} k}{|B|} $$
$$ \frac{\sum_{k \in A_{i+1}} k}{|A_i|} \leq \frac{\sum_{k \in B_i} k}{|B_i|} \text{ for all } i \in \{1, ..., n\}$$
Does it imply
$$\frac{\sum_{k \in A_2 \cup ... \cup A_{n+1}} k}{|A|} \leq \frac{\sum_{k \in B_1 \cup ... \cup B_n} k}{|B|} $$
(note that the final inequality on the left-hand side excludes $A_1$)

**My current workings so far:**
$$\frac{\sum_{k \in A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n} k}{|A|} \leq \frac{\sum_{k \in B_1 \cup ... \cup B_n} k}{|B|} \text{   from (1)}$$
$$\frac{\sum_{k \in A_2 \cup ... \cup A_{n+1}} k}{|A|} \leq \frac{\sum_{k \in B_1 \cup ... \cup B_n} k}{|B|} + \frac{\sum_{k \in A_{n+1} } k- \sum_{k \in A_1} k}{|A|}$$
How do I prove $ \sum_{k \in A_{n+1} } k- \sum_{k \in A_1} k \leq 0$? (If we can do so, we're done!)

Comment: The partition has something to do with the ordering. It imposes a restriction that e.g. the minimum element of $A_i$ is ≥ the maximum element of $A_{i+1}$

Comment: Er isn't that implied by the ordering? Edited the question to make it more explicit :)